# Trouble determining various elements in a text-file read in program (java)

Tags: java, file, text, arraylist

I am having trouble determining how to split separate elements in a text file in a usable way. My program is meant read in a text file to an arraylist, display the possible answers, ask for an answer and move on only when a correct answer is given. The trouble is, the text files must have different numbers of answers, so there is no numerical way to determine when a question is found in the text file and how many questions there are. Here is an example of a quiz text file:

How many licks does it take to get to the tootsie roll center of a tootsie pop?(**QUESTION**)

4(**NUMERICAL VALUE ASSIGNED TO CORRECT ANSWER**)

(**POSSIBLE ANSWERS**)

one

two

three

four

What is your name?

3

Arthur, King of the Britons

Sir Lancelot the Brave

Sir Robin the Not-Quite-So-Brave-As-Sir Lancelot

Who's on first?

5

What

Why

Because

Who

I don't know

I hate asking you guys a broad logic question as such, but I'm really stuck on this. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class JavaApplication8 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner inScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String file_name;
    System.out.print("What is the full file path name?\n>>");
    file_name = inScan.next();

    Scanner fScan = new Scanner(new File(file_name));
    ArrayList<String> Questions = new ArrayList();



    while (fScan.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        Questions.add(fScan.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.println(Questions.get(0));
    System.out.println(Questions.get(2));
    System.out.println(Questions.get(3));
    System.out.println(Questions.get(4));
    System.out.println(Questions.get(5));


    String guess;
    System.out.print("What is your answer?\n>>");
    guess = inScan.next();

    if (guess == Questions.get(1))
    {
        System.out.println("Correct");
    }

    else

        System.out.println("Incorrect");






}
```

**I did not code for the additional questions, only the first one.

Comment: To ask a broad question is one issue, but I don't see any question at all in your post above. Please clarify and ask one.

Comment: How do I go about determining when a question exists in a text file? I would normally count the number of lines in the text file and split them evenly by division, then there must be an uneven number of possible questions per answer.

Comment: As I see it, you file format is not going to help you as you have an inconsistent number of possible answers without being able to identify how many there should be (the first 2 have 4, the last one has 5)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Now you see my problem. This is obviously not a rule I imposed on myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the only instance of a question mark `?` is when there is a question.  Test each line from the file to see if there is a question mark in that line.  If so, then that's a new question/answer set.

Comment: To find a text questionmark, you could use the `indexOf(s)` function for Strings: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: That's definitely extremely helpful. I will look up the use of delimiters. But the question remains of how to determine how many possible answers there are. For each question I must print the possible answers along with the question. For my question I didn't actually include the whole text file. Following possible answers there are three numbers which indicate other certain properties of the quiz (times answered correct/incorrect) that I must ammend

Comment: The end would probably be the only time that a numeric value follows an answer directly, correct?  (i.e. The "right answer" inputs immediately follow a question--not an answer choice)  Thus, check if the input line contains `?`.  If yes, you have a new question to deal with.  If no, check if it is a digit and that the last input was not a new question.  If so, you have reached the numbers at the EOF.  Otherwise, you have an answer choice.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. I was hoping there'd be a solution mentioned in lecture, but alas not

Comment: Glad to be of help!  Please "accept" my solution if believe it to be satisfactory--thanks. ;)

Comment: @anorton That's a great suggestion, I'd be concerned though that an answer might contain the deliminator, but what other choice you got ;)

Comment: That is true, but aside from natural language processing or some form of AI, I don't think you have much choice... :P  Also, from the way the OP was talking, it sounds as if this is for some homework--thus, he could always ask the teacher if such a situation were to be encountered...